# Can I view the email properties in one line in Outlook.com like one can in Outlook 2013?

Tags: outlook.com

It'd help me better manage my emails if I could view the subject and sender of an email in one line instead of two:

[image: Two line example]

Like one can in Outlook 2013:

[image: One line example]

Is there any way to do this in Outlook.com ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose
Message Preview = Off

Comment: Thanks, turning reading pane off in the current version of Outlook.com puts emails in one line. However, in Outlook 2019 one can have the single line email view even with the reading pane on. How can I do that on Outlook.com?